# Angular2+Spring Boot : Unable to resolve context path issue | No data on frontend

Tags: node.js, spring, angular, tomcat, spring-boot

I have created an `Angular2+SpringBoot` web application which I am trying to deploy on a single server `Tomcat`which I am able to run successfully.

However, am not able to understand the context path generated or how will the request flow from UI to backend `Rest service` and populate the data.

I have few dropdown menus at UI which I am populating by a service call but data is not fetched.

Take a look at `form component`: showing two dropdown calls

```
   getBrands() {
    this.http.get('/brands')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => { this.brandsArray = data;
                  this.brand = this.defaultStringValue;
        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('All brands fetched.'));
  }
  getNetworks() {
    this.http.get('/mylab/networks')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => { this.networksArray = data;
                  this.network = this.defaultStringValue;
        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('All networks fetched.'));
  }
```

This is how the proxy.json looks like:

```
{
"/mylab" :{
"target" : "http://localhost:8081",
"secure" : false
}
}
```

And here is the backend service:

```
 @RestController
 public class DropDownController {

   @Autowired
   DropDownService dropdownService;


/**
 * Returns list of brands to populate dropdown
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/brands", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<String> getBrands(){
    return dropdownService.getBrands();
}

/**
 * Returns list of networks to populate dropdown
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/networks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<String> getPlatform(){
    return dropdownService.getNetworks();
}

}
```

The browser console outputs shows following errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/brands    404 Not Found     2ms
GET http://localhost:8081/mylab/networks  404 Not Found  1ms
```

which clearly shows both the paths are not resolved.

Also, the `pom.xml` showing the build information:

```
<build>
        <finalName>MyLab</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${angular.project.location}</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>${angular.project.nodeinstallation}</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- It will install nodejs and npm -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v9.2.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- It will execute command "npm install" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- It will execute command "npm build" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory 
                        to clean and create "/dist" directory -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin to copy the content of /angular/dist/ directory to output 
            directory (ie/ /target/transactionManager-1.0/) -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/${angular.project.location}/dist</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Can you share the annotated part of your rest controller declaration, and context configuration section of your springboot project.

Comment: Updated the backend service code. There is no context configuration.

Comment: have you checked the value of `server.contextPath`? this could give you a hint where spring exposed the API

Answer (score 0):

you should state in your application.yml or properties file the following:

```
server:
 host: 0.0.0.0
 port: your port
 contextPath: /your-service
```

I dont see mylab path defined in your controller class. 
looks like this is what is missing.

Comment: where do we specify this `application.yml` file? I only have `application.properties`.

Comment: the file should be under resources folder.
you can add the content to the properties file (and not create a yml file), just make sure you use the right format

Answer (score 0):

Open your `application.properties` file and add the following 2 lines.

```
port: 8081
server.contextPath=/mylab
```

Then try the following URL

```
http://localhost:8081/mylab/networks
```

If your application has no other errors and stared, above URL should work.

Comment: Did the same. Not worked. The error now is `GET http://localhost:8081/mylab/brands 404 Not Found`

Comment: If it doesn't work, you must have configured the context path grammatically.  Or you might have separate tomcat installation which runs in port 8081. By default embedded tomcat server runs in port 8080. Can you share your configuration classes and the log written into console while your application starting?.